# can the domain of a function change

Tags: functions

is it possible for the domain of a function to change, for example:
we have: $f(x) = \frac{x^2-4}{x+2}$ the domain is $D_{f} = ]-\infty;-2[\cup]-2,+\infty[$

but: $f(x) = \frac{x^2-2^2}{x+2} = \frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x+2} = x-2$

$f(x) = x-2$ the domain is $D_{f} = ]-\infty;+\infty[$

So can anyone explain.

Comment: Technically the domain and range are both part of the function's definition so if you change the domain you change the function. This is important when considering the properties of the function such as injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: Simplifying algebraically will remove ... removable discontinuities, i.e. "holes" from the graph of a function. The new function is not the same, although most graphing software would show them as being the same, since the removed discontinuities are infinitely small.